# Date format issue float to mm.yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: sql-server

```
Declare @col float =01.2022
```

Mm/yyyy format

I need output as date as
2022-01-01
YYYY-MM-DD
And YYYY/MM/DD FORMAT

Comment: Huh? Why in the world would use a float to represent a date? And you should not worry about the format of your date, you should return a date or datetime. Formatting belongs in the front end.

Comment: `Declare @col float = '2022-01-01'; SELECT CONVERT(varchar(30), @col, 23), CONVERT(varchar(30), @col, 111)`

Comment: No, input is mm.yyyy format only need to add default day as 1

Comment: I thought that I'd seen every terrible way to store dates by now, but this is actually a brand new one. I would have never conceived of it. In that light: are you sure your input is a `FLOAT` and not, say, a `DECIMAL` or even a `VARCHAR` that looks `FLOAT`-y? Is this data in a table somewhere, or something you generate yourself as an intermediate step?

Comment: `DECLARE @date = TRY_CONVERT(date,'01.' + {Your Paramater as a varchar},104);`? Trying to shove a date into a float is just a terrible idea; especially when that value is `01.2022`...

Comment: I think it's flot only in a table in mm.yyyy format

Comment: So you are *storing* these values in a table as a `float`? That is a **terrible** design. It ***needs*** fixing.

Comment: `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT('1.', CONVERT(DECIMAL(6, 4), @col)), 104)` would do it (you can convert the `DATE` further to any string representation you please), but please, for the love of all that is holy, try to fix the source instead. The intermediate conversion to `DECIMAL` to make *sure* we get no issues with rounding in the string representation is not strictly necessary, but I wouldn't trust it without it.

Comment: Which data type would you prefer for mm.yyyy format excel input

Comment: In Excel, that should be stored as text: `="01.2022"` (assuming you couldn't just use a date there to begin with, of course). Probably `="01-2022"` is better to prevent any possible confusion with a number if copy-pasted somewhere.

Comment: While importing it shows float from source

Comment: I imagine it would, that's because if you enter "01.2022" in Excel it will interpret it as a number, of course. The suggestion therefore is to fix the source data: "01-2022" would not be similarly "converted".

Comment: I can't modifie the source but need to handle and store in a table like yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: So, considering that you are storing these dates as a `float` (again, just don't), I *assume* that for a "date" like `2000-07-01` you are storing `7.2`? and a date like `2020-03-01` as `3.202`?

Comment: No, 07.2000 (mm.yyyy)storing like this but  I want to chage this to 2000-07-01

Comment: @ajay , Check what happens when you run `SELECT CONVERT(float,07.2000);` You don't get `07.2000` back (you get `7.2`). If the value *is* stored as `07.2000` is *isn't* a `float`.

Comment: @Larnu: good call & big oof, hadn't even considered that. `SELECT CONVERT(DATE, FORMAT(7.2, '1\.00.0000', 'en-US'), 104)` would be the thing, then.

Comment: Blarg, `FORMAT` is terribly slow. Fortunately (?) it seems that style `104` is "happy" to receive 1 digit months, so `TRY_CONVERT(date,CONCAT('01.',CONVERT(decimal(6,4),FloatValue)),104)` would work.

Comment: The root issue here is that your entire Excel column should at least be formatted as text to avoid the type confusion. Is this imported as .csv or .xls?